How to Train an LSTM Model on Multiple Missions and Use it to Predict Full Trajectories Based on Initial Conditions?
I’m working on training an LSTM model for a robotics application (I've been testing different MLs). I have data from multiple "missions," each consisting of 900 time steps. Each time step includes:
Inputs (theta_vector): A state vector with 4 values [theta_0, theta_cmd, theta_dot_0, thetadot_cmd].
Target (f_value): A single control input value corresponding to the time step.
Training:
Train the LSTM model to learn temporal dependencies within each mission (i.e., how theta_vector evolves and corresponds to f_value over 900 time steps).
Generalize the model across missions by training it on data from all missions.
During training, I provide data for all time steps in all missions (e.g., theta_vector and corresponding f_value at each time step).
Inference:
At inference time, provide only the initial condition (first time step's theta_vector).
Predict the full control input trajectory (f_value) for all 900 time steps.
The model should generate the trajectory without requiring explicit dynamics modeling (the temporal relationships should be learned from the training data).
Problem:
I’m not sure how to do it and also I don't know how to structure the training and inference pipeline correctly in PyTorch. Specifically:
Inference:
Given the initial condition, how do I set up the LSTM to generate the full control input trajectory for 900 time steps? Should I iteratively feed the predicted f_value back into the model for the next time step?
Is that even possible to achieve? Namely training in time step way but then feeding initial condition and receive the result (according some papers it is possible for transformers, however I haven't found any details on how it was implemented)?
Instead of LSTM we are going to use Transformers as well to see how differently they perform? Is it easier to put it in transfermer way?
What I’ve Tried:
I created a PyTorch DataLoader to batch the missions and trained the LSTM on sequences of [theta_vector] with [f_value] as the target.
For inference, I attempted to feed the initial_condition as input and iteratively generate the trajectory using the model. However, I faced issues with maintaining correct input/output shapes and updating the hidden states for subsequent time steps.
